# Etherscan API, the input field value of erc20 transactions is always deprecated?

Tags: etherscan

I used to use ABIs to decode the `input` field of token transactions.
I notices recently that the input field has always the value `deprecated`.

You can try the example provided in Etherscan API page:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

If you click on the link above you can see that the value of the input is always deprecated.

I think I have missed something here?
Is there now another approach or API to bring the input and decode it?

Comment: You're expecting users to click the link above with what Api-Key exactly???

Comment: it will work without any API key, this is the exact link provided in Etherscan API tutorial page. No need for API key when you are not calling it very frequently. it will work if you just click.

Comment: You can explain what that field used to stand for, and perhaps someone would no an alternative approach.

Comment: You could certainly use the `hash` field to look up the transaction by hash and see it's data field there. But perhaps you don't need to decode the data at all, given that the `from`, `to`, and `value` fields are already provided.

Comment: actually I need access to the input data. Please have a look at this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x794e1f83b3f82d143909033f91d7f341f338eeb04529da78bfb5e0fea3b15a7d it is one of the transactions that appear in the response for the example link I provided... it clearly has "Input Data" (if you click on the "Click to see More"), but this field has the value 'deprecated' in the API response.

Comment: Input field is not deprecated in Ethereum, perhaps since it is a propietary API from Etherscan they decided to not provide since they already provide other fields with the required info.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'Normal' transaction endpoint instead of the token transfer events endpoint, then the input data will be included.

See example:
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

And the documentation: https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address